# I install apps on OS X 10.9.5, Then They Disappear

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, imovie, launchpad

I have a problem with my iMac  where I install an app from the App Store, it says it’s installed, but then I check the Launchpad and the app is not there. Some important details you may need to help solve this are: my OS is OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks, and I’m installing iMovie from the App Store. Do you know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Logan

Comment: Absolutely everything about Launchpad is terrible and I wish it didn't exist. Are the apps in your Applications folder?

Comment: whats wrong with Launchpad?  i don't useit but curious about the problems.

Comment: Where did you look in launchpad?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy no, they are not in my Applications folder either. I have no clue what even happened. It’s not working with GarageBand either.

Comment: @Natsfan the launchpad is the app to launch your applications. I open it, and all my programs are there, except for iMovie.

Comment: What version of iMovie is being offered by the App Store? What does the App Store say under compatibility for the version of iMovie it offers?  For the current version 10.2.3 it says macOS 10.15.6 or later.

Comment: From your other post it looks like you have been installing versions of iMovie not from the App Store.  If so, you have probably messed up your system and will need to clean up remains left by likely incompatible iMovie as well as any malware.

Comment: @Gilby thanks! I just reinstalled Mavericks, and iLife ‘13. iMovie 10.0.5 is running fine. I am now going to have High Sierra (the latest I can run) on a small partition on my hard disk. Thanks!